# cakePHP validation not working at all

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

*cake version 2.0*

I am working on a cakePHP project and I can't get the validation function to work correctly.

I submit data to the Payment table (Model) through the Order Controller.

Here is the **view**.

```
echo $this->Form->create("Payment",array("class"=>"payment"));
    echo $this->Form->input("Payment.PaymentID");
    echo $this->Form->input("Payment.OrderID",array("value"=>$order["Order"]["OrderID"],"type"=>"hidden"));
    echo $this->Form->input("Payment.UserID",array("type"=>"hidden","value"=>$loggedInUserID));
    echo $this->Form->input("Payment.TransactionTypeID",array("class"=>"transaction","options"=>$transactions,"label"=>"Transaction Type","empty"=>"Select Transaction Type"));

    echo $this->Html->div("transactionType Phone");
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.NameOnCheck",array("class"=>"CheckBy Phone"));
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.CheckRoutingNumber");
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.CheckAccountNumber");  
    echo "</div>";

    echo $this->Html->div("transactionType CreditCard clearfix");
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.CreditCardNumber",array("label"=>"Card Number"));
        echo $this->Form->input("CreditCardExpirationMonth",array("label"=>"Expiration Date","options"=>$months));
        echo $this->Form->input("CreditCardExpirationYear",array("label"=>" ","options"=>$years));
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.CreditCardExpirationDate",array("type"=>"hidden"));
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.CreditCardCVV",array("label"=>"CVV (not required)","class"=>"noCharge"));
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.CreditCardStreet",array("label"=>"Street Address on Card (not required)","class"=>"noCharge"));
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.CreditCardZipCode",array("Zip Code","class"=>"noCharge"));
    echo "</div>";

    echo $this->Html->div("transactionType AmountPaid clearfix");
        echo $this->Form->input("Payment.PaymentAmount",array("label"=>"Amount Paid"));
        echo $this->Form->input("Pay In Full",array("type"=>"button","label"=>" "));
    echo "</div>";

    echo $this->Html->div("transactionType RefundAmount");
        echo $this->Form->input("RefundAmount",array("label"=>"Amount To Refund"));
    echo "</div>";



echo $this->Form->end("Complete Transaction");
```

**controller**

```
 $this->Order->Payment->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->request->is("post") || $this->request->is("put")) {



            if($this->Order->Payment->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash("Payment Added");
               //$this->redirect("add_payment/$id");
            }

        }
```

**Payment Model**

```
class Payment extends AppModel{
public $useTable = "Payment";
public $primaryKey = "PaymentID";
public $belongsTo = array(
    "TransactionType"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"TransactionTypeID"
    )
);
    public $validate = array(
        "NameOnCheck" => array(
            "rule" => "notBlank"
        )
    );
```

One of the problems is, whenever I submit the form with data in the NameOnCheck field, it gives me an error saying that is blank.

It also doesn't account for all the validations I am setting. When I make a validation for the length of CheckRoutingNumber, it just ignores it and only gives me an error for NameOnCheck (whether it is filled in or not).

I also get this warning at the top, twice:

> preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 3198]

Does anyone have a solution for this, any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using non-standard field names?  Not sure if that could have anything to do with it, but - something to look into.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja You're answer might essentially  be correct, as `notBlank` was first introduced in 2.7, and the OP didn't specify the version in use. That being said, OP, please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using!

Comment: @ndm I believe it is version 2.0,

Comment: @drmonkeyninja what do you mean non standard field names? Do you mean field names that go along with cake conventions? I am working on  a project that has already been started

Comment: `2.0` is barely a branch, the exact version number is in `x.x.x` format, and can be found for example in `lib\Cake\VERSION.txt`. Also the first comment is from @Dave, I've just added drmonkeyninja as he had posted an answer, but deleted it ;)

Comment: Yes, I mean field names that don't follow the cake conventions.

Comment: Per @drmonkeyninja temporary answer, try "notEmpty" if you're using an older than 2.7 version of Cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have defined it elsewhere the rule `notBlank` should be [`notEmpty`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::notEmpty) to make a field required (for CakePHP below 2.7 as is your case):-

```
public $validate = array(
    "NameOnCheck" => array(
        "rule" => "notEmpty"
    )
);
```

Cake is giving you the error message `preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash` because `notBlank` is not a defined rule in your app so is treating it as a custom regular expression rule.

As Dave states in his comment for CakePHP 2.7+ you should use `notBlank`.

Comment: `notEmpty` is deprecated.  `notBlank` is correct:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::notEmpty

Comment: @Dave OP is using a version older than 2.7 so my answer is still relevant. I've updated it to make it clearer.

Comment: @Dave, ndm thanks for your help guys, its working now with notEmpty! :)

Comment: does anyone know how I can validate if something is a certain length (9)? range (9,9) and between isn't working

Comment: @Anthony this should be asked as a new question.